# React: usePrevious hook only works if there is 1 state in the component. How to make it work if there are multiple states?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state) suggests the folllowing to get previous state:

```
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const prevCount = usePrevious(count);
  return <h1>Now: {count}, before: {prevCount}</h1>;
}

function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}
```

Per my understanding, this works fine only if there is exactly one state in the component. However consider the following where there are multiple states:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useContext } from "react";


function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(0);
  const prevCount = usePrevious(count);

  return (
    <div>
    <button onClick={() => setFoo(f => f+1)}> Update foo </button>
     <h1>Now: {count}, before: {prevCount}</h1>
  </div>);
}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/little-feather-wow4m

When a different state  (`foo`) is updated, the usePrevious hook returns the *latest* value for count, as opposed to the previous one).

Is there a way to reliably get the previous value for a state/prop when there are multiple states?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is the right approach.

How about a custom hook that sets up the state and returns a custom setter function that handles this logic for you.

```
function useStateWithPrevious(initial) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initial)
  const [prev, setPrev] = useState(initial)

  function setValueAndPrev(newValue) {
    if (newValue === value) return // optional, depends on the logic you want.
    setPrev(value)
    setValue(newValue)
  }

  return [prev, value, setValueAndPrev]
}
```

Which you would use like:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [prevCount, count, setCount] = useStateWithPrevious(0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create an altered version of your hook that does seem to work:

```js
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef([undefined, undefined]);
  if (ref.current[0] !== value) {
    ref.current = [value, ref.current[0]];
  }
  return ref.current[1];
}
```

Playground [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-galois-516f2?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Nice one! This seems robust

Comment: @nz_21 Make sure to mark the answer as the solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping track of only the previous value of some state is not a very common use case. Hence there's no need to overthink it or try to "trick" React with refs to achieve a slightly shorter syntax. There's almost always a few ways to get the same result in a more straightforward and maintainable manner.

React's [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state) also stress that this suggested approach is only for edge cases.

> This is rarely needed and is usually a sign you have some duplicate or redundant state.

If the previous count is de facto part of the application state (it's used in rendering just like the current count), it's counter productive to not just store it as such. Once it's in state, it's just a matter of making state updates in event listeners **update all parts of the state in one go**, making it inherently safe with React's concurrent features.

### Method 1: Set multiple state variables at the same time

Just create an additional state variable for the old value, and make your handler set both values.

```
const initialCount = 0;

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
  const [prevCount, setPrevCount] = useState(initialCount);

  return <>
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        // You can memoize this callback if your app needs it.
        setCount(count + 1);
        setPrevCount(count);
      }}
    >Increment</button>
    <span>Current: {count} </span>
    <span>Previous: {prevCount} </span>
  </>
}
```

You can almost always do this instead, it offers the same functionality as `usePrevious` and obviously will never lead to the application using the wrong combination of values. In fact, because of batched state updates since React 18 there's no performance penalty in calling 2 setters in one event handler.

Using a hook like `usePrevious` doesn't really bring any overall benefits. Clearly both the current and the previous value are pieces of state your application needs for rendering. They can both use the same simple and readable syntax. Just because `usePrevious` is shorter doesn't mean it's easier to maintain.

### Method 2: `useReducer`

If you want to avoid the 2 function calls in the event listener, you can use `useReducer` to encapsulate your state. This hook is particularly well suited for updates of complex but closely related state. It guarantees the application state transitions to a new valid state in one go.

```
const initialState = { count: 0, prevCount: 0, foo: 'bar' };

function countReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case: 'INCREMENT':
      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count + 1,
        prevCount: state.count,
      };
    case 'DO_SOMETHING_ELSE':
      // This has no effect on the prevCount state.
      return {
        ...state,
        foo: payload.foo,
      }
        
  }
  return state;
}

function App() {
  const [
    { count, prevCount },
    dispatch
  ] = useReducer(countReducer, initialState)

  return <>
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' });
      }}
    >Increment</button>
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        dispatch({
          type: 'DO_SOMETHING_ELSE',
          payload: { foo: `last update: ${prevCount} to  ${count`} },
        );
      }}
    >Do foo</button>
    <span>Current: {count} </span>
    <span>Previous: {prevCount} </span>
  </>
}
```