# Concurrent-safe version of useLatest in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

There's a commonly used utility hook "useLatest", which returns a ref containing the latest value of the input. There are 2 common implementations:

```
const useLatest = <T>(value: T): { readonly current: T } => {
  const ref = useRef(value);
  ref.current = value;
  return ref;
};
```

From https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/useLatest.ts

```
const useLatest = <T extends any>(current: T) => {
  const storedValue = React.useRef(current)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    storedValue.current = current
  })
  return storedValue
}
```

From https://github.com/jaredLunde/react-hook/blob/master/packages/latest/src/index.tsx

The first version isn't suitable for React 18's concurrent mode, the second version will return the old value if used before `useEffect` runs (e.g. during render).

Is there a way to implement this that's both concurrent-safe and consistently returns the correct value?

Here's my attempt:

```
function useLatest<T>(val: T): React.MutableRefObject<T> {
  const ref = useRef({
    tempVal: val,
    committedVal: val,
    updateCount: 0,
  });
  ref.current.tempVal = val;
  const startingUpdateCount = ref.current.updateCount;

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    ref.current.committedVal = ref.current.tempVal;
    ref.current.updateCount++;
  });

  return {
    get current() {
      // tempVal is from new render, committedVal is from old render.
      return ref.current.updateCount === startingUpdateCount
        ? ref.current.tempVal
        : ref.current.committedVal;
    },
    set current(newVal: T) {
      ref.current.tempVal = newVal;
    },
  };
}
```

This hasn't been thoroughly tested, just wrote it while writing this question, but it seems to work most of the time. It should be better than both versions above, but it has 2 issues: it returns a different object every time and it's still possible to be inconsistent in this scenario:

Render 1:

1. ref1 = useLatest(val1)
2. Create function1, which references ref1
3. Commit (useLayoutEffect runs)

Render 2:

1. useLatest(val2)
2. Call function1

function1 will use val1, but it should use val2.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68473314/14274597) might help? It's similar to the 2nd version, but we only store the new value if it's different from the currently stored value. The only issue with that is that if for some reason it gets intentionally called with the same value twice, it won't update the stored value.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava that problem should be resolved with useLayoutEffect, which bvaughn started doing later on: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16956#issuecomment-536636418

Comment: There's only a bug if "you were to ever pass the callback it creates as a prop to a child component", using the callback in the current component is fine

Comment: I inclined to say (based on your own answer to my question) that the second version should work if you chance `useEffect` to `useLayoutEffect`.

Comment: @Izhaki if you access ref.current right afterwards, it'll be the old value

Comment: @LeoJiang if `useLayoutEffect` works in @izhaki-s case, why not in your case?

Comment: "@Izhaki if you access ref.current right afterwards, it'll be the old value" Not sure I get this. What does "right afterwards" mean?

Comment: @Izhaki `console.log(useLatest(foo).current);` would have the wrong value

Comment: @LeoJiang can you please define "wrong". What value do you consider "correct"? The "correct" value is that that is committed to the DOM (as set in `useLayoutEffect`), that's the whole point here no?

Comment: Correct would be always the latest, like the first example, but safe for concurrent mode.

Comment: But that first example is not correct because you do not know if that value has been committed to the DOM (more so in concurrent mode). Only in the effect stage you can be certain the DOM has been committed, and `useLayoutEffect` also ensures not intervals or timeouts between the DOM being committed and the effect being called.

Comment: Are subtle concurrent mode dangers like this documented anywhere besides random GH issue threads??  I can't find any discussion of this in React's documentation pages.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I think is correct:

```js
const useLatest = <T extends any>(current: T) => {
  const storedValue = React.useRef(current)
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    storedValue.current = current
  })
  return storedValue.current
}
```

Comment: Repeating here since the comment's buried: this doesn't meet the criteria of needing to work in the render, i.e. `console.log(useLatest(foo).current);` returns the old value

Comment: OK. That's because we are using refs here and these will not re-render anything. I guess the question is: What is the actual use case, as in, what is it we are trying to store as latest? Can you create a codesandbox with an example maybe?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to implement this that's both concurrent-safe and consistently returns the correct value?

The question doesn't actually explain what "this" means, i.e. how is `useLatest` called, and what purpose it fulfills in the application. So I'll have to guess for that ;) A somewhat realistic example would be very helpful.

In any case, it's probably useful to take a step back and ask if `useLatest` is the most suitable solution. If you find you don't need it, you also won't have to fix it.

With the way it works (depending on an effect to capture the value), it indeed won't play well with concurrent features. But even without them, it's an unreliable approach as the ref theoretically can change at any point, making renders unpredictable.

My guess of the use case is something similar to the proposed (and partially accepted) [`useEvent` hook](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/useevent/text/0000-useevent.md) ([GitHub PR](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/220)).

```
function Chat() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  const onClick = useEvent(() => {
    sendMessage(text);
  });

  return <SendButton onClick={onClick} />;
}
```

Its purpose is to capture the latest render's scope, like `useCallback`, but without the need for dependencies. It does this by using an unchanging callback that internally calls the latest created callback, in a ref that is re-assigned on every render. That way passing that callback as a prop won't cause any renders by itself.

You can implement this yourself already, but the [RFC](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/useevent/text/0000-useevent.md#internal-implementation) mentions some open questions about this approach.

```
export function useEvent(handler) {
    const latestHandlerRef = useRef();
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        latestHandlerRef.current = handler;
    });

    // Never changing callback.
    return useCallback((...args) => {
        latestHandlerRef.current(...args)
    }, []);
}
```

I also tested setting `latestHandlerRef.current = handler` directly in render instead of the layout effect. For now this seems to work as expected but that's just my use case. In the PR [some doubt](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/220#issuecomment-1118027152) is expressed over assigning to a ref during render, though possibly these concerns don't really apply here, as the ref is only ever accessed in the callback.